# Rounding off incorrectly in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

So when I give the 1st digit after the decimal point as 4 or 5 or 8, I get an incorrectly rounded value as output (shown in 'CASE 1' below). But when I use other numbers (1,2,3,5,6,9,0) in the same place I get the expected result (shown in 'CASE 2' below). Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
--CASE 1
DECLARE @factor float = 0.425,
        @amount money = 1
SELECT CONVERT(money, ROUND(@factor * @amount, 2))
--output is 0.42 (should be 0.43)

--CASE 2
SET @factor = 0.625  
SELECT CONVERT(money, ROUND(@factor * @amount, 2))
--output is 0.63 (correct)
```

Please note, this got fixed by using another variable to store the product - '@factor * @amount' and then use that variable to get the rounding off value. But I am just curious why would I see the discrepancy before.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output of the first case is `0.42`, not `0.425` as you say (checked because that would be a more surprising outcome)

Comment: Please try to reproduce your problem on something like dbfiddle, because at present, everything ***appears*** to be working fine to me *(perhaps you've simplified the problem and in doing so have removed the cause of your problem?)*  [db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c621c517dd0d1e58999c9cb4ca1662e)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever- Sorry, that was a typo. I have edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the values are just at the brink. 0.425 and 0.625 would get rounded up, while for instance 0.42499999999999 and 0.62499999999999 would get rounded down.

You are using `FLOAT`, which is not a precise data type, but an approximate one. You can hence only expect approximate results.

If you want exact results, use an exact type like `DECIMAL`.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15